# iOS: wrong UITextField color of selected UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiappearance

I have an issue with UITextField color which belongs to UITableViewCell when it's selected.

I have changed default UITableViewCell selection color using the following code that is being called from AppDelegate when application is launched with parameters:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = backgroundColor
UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = backgroundColor
UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = tintColor
let colorView = UIView()
colorView.backgroundColor = ColorThemes.uiTableViewCellSelectedBackgroundColor
UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = colorView

UITextField.appearance().textColor = ColorThemes.textColorNormal
UITextField.appearance().backgroundColor = ColorThemes.uiTextFieldBackgroundColor
UITextField.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.gray
UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = ColorThemes.uiKeyboardAppearance
```

This code was taken from the Internet and from one of StackOverflow's answers.

Everything is fine with normal cells with labels. But I have an issue with UITableViewCells that have UITextField inside it. When cell just has been selected selected, it's highlighted with green and text field looks fine.
But other cells, that were selected previously (in selected state) have an issue with text field color. It's clear on the pictures below.
[image]
I have checked UI Hierarchy, and printed description of all three views, and all of them have the same description:
[image]

```
Printing description of $30:
<_UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue: 0x7fdeb209ac80; frame = (0 0; 70 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000280d980>>
Printing description of $31:
<_UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue: 0x7fdeaedb2b30; frame = (0 0; 70 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002801180>>
Printing description of $32:
<_UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue: 0x7fdeb209e090; frame = (0 0; 70 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tintColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 1 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000287ac60>>
```

Comment: "This code was taken from the Internet and from one of StackOverflow's answers."

This is probably where the problem began. First of all, I'd recommend not using `.appearance()` as it applies globally. There are use cases, but the quote above makes me think there wasn't a use case for it. Instead you can just give the textfield and cell's view a background color, then when the cell is selected, updated the cell's view backgroundColor property.

Comment: @KyleH well, I wanted to make it globally. I just did not expect this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per KyleH's advice, I have added the following code to my table view with UITextField inside:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CommonMenuTableViewCell
    cell.itemPriceTextField.backgroundColor = ColorThemes.uiTextFieldBackgroundColor

}
```

I've set desired color to UITextField background color property.